# integrate wget with opera 27

Tags: linux-mint, wget, opera

I want to integrate wget into opera, I didn't find anything on the web except this article http://archive09.linux.com/feature/59457 which is old(back to 2007) and I didn't find tools->preferences

my opera is 27 and I'm running linux mint 17.1 64bit cinnamon, I looked in opera's help, they don't mention using external download manager.

### PS

the reason for using an external manager is that opera's own manager doesn't have resume or it doesn't work(it didn't work for me).

Answer (score 0):

Opera’s download manager should support pausing and resuming; assuming the server supports it.

Opera 15+ does not support remote download managers. Well, it kind of does. You could hook up against one using the [downloads extensions API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads). But you would need a wrapper to receive redirected calls from Opera.

Copying the links and pasting them into the terminal sounds like the path of least resistance.